# How to automate (semi-auto) a method to format usb flash drives

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I am trying to automate a process for formatting usb flash drives. I have read up and tried all the available info but am still not successful. I am using a .BAT file to run a set of commands as below:

```
Format e: /v:Demo /fs:FAT32 /q
```

The command works, however I need to input a further command to simulate a keystroke as when it runs, it pops up a box stating

```
"Insert new disk for drive E:
and press ENTER when ready..."
```

How would I be able to emulate a keystroke for the process to continue without me having to physically press a key.

Thanking you

Comment: Try `echo. | format ...` (the dot must immediately follow the `echo`).

Comment: @harrymc thank you sir...that worked perfectly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass a new-line character to the `format` command, use:

```
echo. | format ...
```

Note that the dot must immediately follow the `echo`.